# Domain will not propagate (Over 96+ Hours)

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, nameserver, internet, domain-name

I'm stumped. I have dozens of domains, but this is my first "ngo" domain. On tuesday (march 15th, 2016), I set the same servers for my domain "sai.ngo" to

- ns-1273.awsdns-31.org
- ns-1547.awsdns-01.co.uk
- ns-72.awsdns-09.com
- ns-789.awsdns-34.net

Reference: http://who.is/whois/sai.ngo

However, when looking up the domain using google domain tools, the domain will not resolve using google name servers or on any root name servers.

- https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/sai.ngo - Nothing
- https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/sai.ngo@192.36.148.17 - root dns server

Nothing seems to be working, unless you query the aws name server directly.

- https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/sai.ngo@ns-1273.awsdns-31.org

This works fine.

Anyone have have any ideas as to why the domains isn't propagating?

Comment: Contact the registrar. Something went wrong on their end.

Comment: @MichaelHampton do you have any idea what they did wrong? What can I ask them to check or do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for my ngo and ong domain to work, it had to be verified by:

https://www.ongood.ngo

They will ask you for primary, and secondary contact information, as well as supporting documentation proving you control a legally registered non-profit organization. A copy of my articles of incorporation was sufficient to be verified.

Answer (score 11):

I'm basically parroting Michael here, but this is too much to paste into a comment:

```
;sai.ngo.                       IN      A
ngo.                    172800  IN      NS      b0.nic.ngo.
ngo.                    172800  IN      NS      d0.nic.ngo.
ngo.                    172800  IN      NS      a2.nic.ngo.
ngo.                    172800  IN      NS      a0.nic.ngo.
ngo.                    172800  IN      NS      b2.nic.ngo.
ngo.                    172800  IN      NS      c0.nic.ngo.
a0.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      A       199.19.56.1
a0.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      AAAA    2001:500:e::1
a2.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      A       199.249.112.1
a2.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      AAAA    2001:500:40::1
b0.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      A       199.19.54.1
b0.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      AAAA    2001:500:c::1
b2.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      A       199.249.120.1
b2.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      AAAA    2001:500:48::1
c0.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      A       199.19.53.1
c0.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      AAAA    2001:500:b::1
d0.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      A       199.19.57.1
d0.nic.ngo.             172800  IN      AAAA    2001:500:f::1
;; Received 395 bytes from 192.203.230.10#53(e.root-servers.net) in 91 ms

;sai.ngo.                       IN      A
ngo.                    900     IN      SOA     a0.nic.ngo. noc.afilias-nst.info. 1000004846 10800 3600 2764800 900
;; Received 88 bytes from 199.19.53.1#53(c0.nic.ngo) in 17 ms
```

You can reproduce that with `dig +trace +question +additional sai.ngo`. This clearly illustrates that the nameservers responsible for `ngo` are not serving up a referral for `sai.ngo`...or even acknowledging its existence. Either `ngo` is having an internal problem, or the name of the domain you registered is not the name that you think it is.

Comment: Given the whois record, it seems to be the right domain name. I wasn't aware that Tucows was still in business, though... :)

Comment: @Michael Yeah, just saw that too. Definitely looking like technical issues internal to the TLD. ...Didn't see the tucows referral link though... ;)

Comment: @AndrewB & MichaelHampton, thank you both for your help. To be honest, the information you provided doesn't mean much to me, but should to the registrar. I've contacted Hover/Tucows pointing them to this thread.

Comment: @AndrewWei The cliff notes are that you should see `sai.ngo. IN NS` prefixed records at the bottom if this domain existed. That's the TLD saying "ask these servers for DNS data". Instead, it's saying *"`sai.ngo`? what's that? never heard of it"*.

Comment: Hover is generally good as I use them and haven't told them to take a flying leap. Talk to their support team, I'm sure it'll get sorted.